# Opencart product ID to current SEO link

Tags: php, seo, opencart, vqmod

Im using an ajax (live-search) by vqmod.
I have enabled my SEO and product links works well. But when i click on a product via the search function its taking me to the old link which is:

```
index.php?route=product/product/&product_id=123
```

My current SEO links looks like this

```
shop/Datorkomponenter/Chassi/Aerocool-DS-Cube-Devil-Red
```

I've searched in the .XML file for the Vqmod and I found this code and maybe its connecting to the old link.

```
select: function(event, ui) {
   if(ui.item.value){
   location = 'index.php?route=product/product/&product_id='+ui.item.value;
     }else{
   $('.button-search').trigger('click');
     }
   return false;
}
```

Is there anyway to change it or modify it? Maybe redirect from .htaccess?

Comment: can you show your .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

The possible ways to handle this would be (in order of decreasing desirableness):

1. return the seo url with the ajax results
2. do a second ajax request to get the seo url
3. redirect once the product page is loaded

In all those scenarios you'll want to use the core Opencart `url` class like this:

```
$url = $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_id);
```

Comment: this is happening on search page and it is opencart default search page.

Comment: That's incorrect.  The default search page uses SEO urls if they are enabled.  you either haven't got them enabled or your search controller has been modified.

Answer (score -1):

You can check with following **.htaccess** code.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/  

RewriteBase /yourshopfolder/
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Create you own htaccess file on root folder and put above code on that. It will work.

I have checked it in open-cart version 2.0.2.0 +

Comment: Its the same setting i had.